# Notification if a modal dialog is shown on top of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jframe, windowlistener

What listener should I register in a `JFrame` instance to be notified if a modal `JDialog` is shown on top of the frame (the frame is the owner of the dialog)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Charles is there reason for edits & remove new Tags, because I'll edits another Swing's rellated threads with these two Tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think JFrame.addWindowListener(...) would work and then pay attention to WindowListener.windowDeactivated(...)

ETA:

```
jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            if(e.getOppositeWindow() instanceof JDialog) {
                JDialog dialog = (JDialog) e.getOppositeWindow();
                if(dialog.isModal()) {
                    // do stuff
                }
            }
        }
    });
```